# How to linq join if datatable doesn't have all the rows

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having an issue where I'm getting nothing back. Here is my code:

```
var final = (from table1 in dtS.AsEnumerable()
                 join table2 in DataDT.AsEnumerable()
                    on table1.Field<string>(1) equals table2.Field<string>(0)
                 join table3 in DataDT2.AsEnumerable() 
                    on table1.Field<string>(1) equals table3.Field<string>(0)
                 join table4 in DataDT3.AsEnumerable()
                    on table1.Field<string>(1) equals table4.Field<string>(0)
                 select new Model
                 {
                     TestID = table1.Field<int>(0),
                     ID = table1.Field<string>(1),
                     Name = table1.Field<string>(2),
                     Absent = table1.Field<bool>(3),
                     Gender = table1.Field<string>(4),
                     Grade = table1.Field<int>(5),
                     TestDate = table1.Field<string>(7),
                     SessionNumber = table1.Field<int>(8),
                     Room = table1.Field<string>(9),
                     Code = table1.Field<string>(10),
                     Booklet = table1.Field<string>(11),
                     Color = table4.Field<string>(3),
                     Accomm = table3.Field<string>(1),
                     SID = table2.Field<string>(1),
                     LocalName = table2.Field<string>(2)

                 }).ToList();
```

If I comment out the last two joins and "Color, Accomm, SID and Local" . I seem to get all of my info.

table1 has 300 rows. This has all the people

table2 has 1000 rows. Has some extra data I need to add

table3 has 10. Has some extra data that I need to add (but doesn't have everyone)

table4 has 17. Has some extra data that I need to add (but doesn't have everyone)

Doesn't seem to "Linq" up (**drums**). Thanks for the help. I know I'm over thinking something..

Comment: Sounds to me like table3 and table4 should be left outer join instead of inner join

Comment: If you are getting nothing back, `table3` and `table4` don't have any matching values. What happens if you search `table3` or `table4` for the values in `table1[0]`?

Comment: @NetMage I'm pretty sure there are, but shouldn't just show null or blank if it doesn't have a value?

Comment: That would be the difference between an inner join and an outer join.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Marcus Hoglund for pointing out the outer join. I was able to make some changes and it's working.

Here you go:

```
var final = (from studData in dtS.AsEnumerable()
                 join table2 in DataDT.AsEnumerable() on studData[1] equals table2[0] into part1

                 from p1 in part1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 join table3 in DataDT2.AsEnumerable() on studData[1] equals table3.Field<string>(0) into part2

                 from p2 in part2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 join table4 in DataDT3.AsEnumerable() on studData[1] equals table4.Field<string>(0) into part3

                 from p3 in part3.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new Model
                 {
                     TestID = table1.Field<int>(0),
                     ID = table1.Field<string>(1),
                     Name = table1.Field<string>(2),
                     Absent = table1.Field<bool>(3),
                     Gender = table1.Field<string>(4),
                     Grade = table1.Field<int>(5),
                     TestDate = table1.Field<string>(7),
                     SessionNumber = table1.Field<int>(8),
                     Room = table1.Field<string>(9),
                     Code = table1.Field<string>(10),
                     Booklet = table1.Field<string>(11),
                     Color = (p3 == null) ? "" : p3[1],
                     Accomm = (p2 == null) ? "" : p2[1],
                     SID = (p1 == null) ? "" : p1[1],
                     LocalName = (p1 == null) ? "" : p1[2],

                 }).ToList();
```

Comment: My minor suggestion would be to call e.g. `part1` `table2j` instead so you understand where it came from.